# Javascript load iframe asynchonous and auto resize

Tags: javascript, iframe, asynchronous, resize

For our website we would like to give users the availability to include content of our website on their own website in an iframe. For this we would like to give the user a little piece of javascript code that they can include on their page without the need of too much programming knowledge. (like e.g. Facebook does for adding facepile to your page)

There are two concerns from my side. I want the content to be loaded asynchronous so the inclusion of our code will not affect original page load times ans secondly I want the script to automaticaly sets the height of the iframe based on the loaded external content.

I do not want to make use of frameworks like jquery, again to make it as simple as possible for a non code aware user.

I hope that someone can point me to the right direction. I've seen a lot of partial answers on the net, but I am looking for a more all in one solution. Any help would be high appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance. Take a look at the "Dynamic async iframe" section. They are using a nice trick by putting a onload event in the iframe document.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this little library for resizing iFrames.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

The code that goes into the iframe, has no dependancies and does nothing until called by the parent page. So it's a good guest on other peoples sites.

All you would need to do is give people a link the js file hosted on your site.